# React-Bootstrap input focused but cannot type

Tags: input, react-bootstrap, caret, autofocus

The issue I'm struggling with is that whenever I click on the `budget-glyph-clear` I still want to be able to be focused (which I am) to the input field and type in it. I get to see the input className correspond to the `formControlDisplayStyle` style when the input should be focused, but I don't see the caret on the input to type (which I am not able to)

Here's my FormControl

```
            <InputGroup className={formControlDisplayStyle}>
                <FormControl 
                    className='budget-input-field'
                    pattern='[0-9]*'
                    type='text'
                    placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                    onChange={this.onInputChange}
                    value={this.props.value}
                    onFocus={this.onFocus}
                    onBlur={this.onBlur}
                    autoFocus={this.props.focused}
                />

                <InputGroup.Addon className='clear-sign budget-addon' style={hideClearButton}>
                    <div className='budget-glyph budget-glyph-clear' onClick={this.onClearClick} />
                </InputGroup.Addon>

            </InputGroup>
```

Could someone shed some light as to why I'm not able to type or see the caret on the focused field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some struggle, I realized what was going on. I also tried adding `ref` as per many google search suggestions, but nothing.

The following code would actually leave the input focused bent to my will!

```
private input: HTMLInputElement;
public componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.focused) {
        this.input.focus();
    }
}
```

The render method

```
<InputGroup className={formControlDisplayStyle}>
    <FormControl 
        className='budget-input-field'
        pattern='[0-9]*'
        type='text'
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        onChange={this.onInputChange}
        value={this.props.value}
        onFocus={this.onFocus}
        onBlur={this.onBlur}
        inputRef={this.updateInputRef}
    />

    <InputGroup.Addon className='clear-sign budget-addon' style={hideClearButton}>
        <div className='budget-glyph budget-glyph-clear' onClick={this.onClearClick} />
    </InputGroup.Addon>

</InputGroup>
```

private method with magic

```
private updateInputRef = (ref: HTMLInputElement) => {
    this.input = ref;
}
```